# How to run a class multiple times?

Tags: java, android, class

I want to run a class multiple times, lets say I have a class

```
public class setTextClass {

    public void setTextClass (String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        textview.setText(text);
    }

    public void run{
        textview.setText(text);
    }
}
```

So, As I see, if I initiate the class doing:

```
setTextClass hi = new setTextClass("hello");
```

The code on the onCreate will run right? (this is my first question)

And then, if I run the code:

```
hi.run()
```

The code over the run method will be executed and also will pass the text variable that was assigned at the initialization?. This is my second question. I'm learning java, sorry if this is a really basic question

Comment: Wait, what does this class extend? How will `onCreate(...)` magically be called on object creation if not called within the constructor?

Comment: Try to read some java tutorial first, you are even mixing up java and android. onCreate is a lifecycle method called by the Android framework. There is no such thing as onCreate in a plain java object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's difficult to address question with basic java and Android misconceptions in a Stack Overflow answer. **SO is not made for these kind of question**, that's why you are getting downvotes. So, that said, I'll try to help you a little bit:

First answer: "The code on the onCreate will run right? (this is my first question)"

No. You are probably mixing up because of `onCreate` method from Android's Activity class, right? But a **constructor** is something general for all classes in java, while `onCreate` is a method specific to some Android complex classes, like Activity or Fragment. It is a method related to the lifecycle of these classes and you should read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

So, in this simple class that you showed, onCreate will not be called in the constructor (unless you explicitly call it in the constructor). You should assign the text to textView inside your constructor.

Second question: "The code over the run method will be executed and also will pass the text variable that was assigned at the initialization?"

Yes, it will run and use the variable assigned to `this.text` on the constructor. BUT, you are missing the declaration of this global variable for it to work:

```
public class setTextClass {

    private TextView textView;
    private String text; // You have to declare your global variables here

    public void setTextClass (TextView textView, String text){ // You should pass your TextView in the constructor and assign it to your global variable, so it's not null when you assign text to it;
       this.textView = textView;
       this.text = text;
       textview.setText(text); // Moved from your onCreate method to the constructor
    }

    public void run{
        textview.setText(text);
    }
}
```

I hope I could make myself clear, but you should study more java and do some basic tutorials to better understand the language and it's concepts, so you can ask more specific questions here. [Read here about classes, objects, constructors and more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: You answer surely clear all my questions, and yes I'm mixing Android and Java, as onCreate is part of an Android Activity and not explicitly from Java.

Sure I will study more, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your onCreate function will not run when you do the initialization:

```
setTextClass hi = new setTextClass("hello");
```

instead what will run as its constructor(which should not have a return type because its return type is the object itself) ie:

```
 public setTextClass (String text){
     this.text = text;
 }
```

And as for the second question the text variable, that variable only exist in the scope of the constructor or setTextClass  method. So if you wanted to do something like that you would need to create and set a class variable.

It seems like you need to do a lot more learning and go through examples of OOP design and scope. I would check out these resources if i were you:

http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Objects

http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions